# XAML-Datagrid jump to row

Tags: c#, list, xaml, datagrid

I'm quite new in programming c# and XAML so I try my best to describe the problem as good as possible.

The issue:

- I have to list the addresses and the values used in an EEPROM.
- In the EEPROM not all addresses are used, so it e.g. in the list appears address-ranges 0...0x0F, 0x20...0x2F and 0x71...0x72.
- The user can delete or add an new item for the EEPROM (meaning deleting or adding new  entries in the list)
- When an new item is inserted it automatically get the first available address. (E.g. if 0x0 to 0x0F is used the new item get the address 0x1F)
- The list has to be shown in order of the addresses.

Now the issue is 98% complete. When the list is shown in the right order and I can add and remove items from the list. ( Thanks to everybody who wrote answers in other topics. I often run in similar problem)

The problem:

To show the list I use Datagrid and Binding in XAML.
The list may be very long so to see the last elements I have to scroll down.
When I have scrolled down and I insert a new item, the element is insert in one of the first elements of the list so I have to scroll up and find out where it was inserted (e.g. to edit it).

My question:
It is possible to automatically jump to the new inserted row?

I have googled a lot since yesterday and I tried a few things I found out, but I don't find a solution.

A snippet of my XAML-file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.RightsConfigView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="800"
  xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:conv">
 ... Background setting ...
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
<DataGrid x:Name="ParamGrid" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"  cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action MouseDoubleClicked]"                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" >
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Value" cal:Message.Attach="CreateNewValue">                            
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete Value" cal:Message.Attach="DeleteValue">
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
 ... Tamplate ...
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

A snippet of the class RightsConfigViewModel looks like:

```
public class RightsConfigViewModel : BaseTabModel, ICloseDetail
{
    public ObservableCollection<ParameterValueModel> Values { get; set; } 
    private void GenerateDisplayList()
    {
          foreach (EEPROMParameter theItem in parameters)
                {
                    ... some cast etc. ...
                    ParameterValueModel theParameterModel = new ParameterValueModel(theItem, this, this);
                    Values.Add(theParameterModel);
                }
           ...
           this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Values);
    }

    public void CreateNewValue()
    {
           // Insert at the right position    
           foreach (ParameterValueModel model in Values)
                {
                   if (tempAddress != model.Parameter.Address)
                   {
                        foundFreeAddress = true;
                        modelToAddBefore = Values.IndexOf(model);
                        break;
                    }
                 }
                 ....
                 Values.Add(newModel);
                 Values.Move(Values.IndexOf(newModel), modelToAddBefore);
                 this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Values);

    }
}
```

In the code-behind I would like to insert in the method the method CreateNewValue() somithing like:

1. Get datagrid used (C#-class get information from XAML).
2. Move or scroll to item (C#-class controlls GUI).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best wishes.

Elvys

Comment: How you are adding item to the grid (from viewmodel or code behind the xaml). can you share the code?

Comment: I think it is called code behind; I add a snippet of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a good solution for my problem:

Basically I used the solution proposed in http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/125583/ScrollIntoView-for-a-DataGrid-when-using-MVVM but with some changes to make it work (for me).

Copied the c#-class like it is and I changed

- The namespace (just to fit it to my project) and
- In the line where the  grid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke I casted the Anonymous function so the line looks like:

```
    grid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( (Action)delegate 
    ...
```

In the method of my viewModel where the new list element is created the new 
element created is refered by the SelectedValue

```
SelectedValue = newModel;
this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SelectedValue);
```

That's all folks!

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ScrollIntoView` method of the `DataGrid` and pass new added item as an argument. In your case you are adding new value to the collection in ViewModel, so you need to notify your UI that the item added to the `DataGrid` and scroll it into view.

Comment: This is what I don't understand. How can I get the object of the DataGrid in min my code. As you can see the method _CreateNewValue_ doesn't have any parameters so i can't use _sender as Datagrid_ to invoke the method ScrollIntoView.

Comment: There are many ways to send an notification to UI that the item added to grid. You need to use one of them or write yours. Do you use any lib for MVVM?

Comment: No, I don't. Can you please send  my a link where I can read more about the topic - not a solution. I want to learn how to do it.

Comment: I am using MVVM Light by GalaSoft in my wpf applications, it has built in messaging service. http://www.mvvmlight.net

Comment: Thank you. Now I have something to read (and test) for the weekend ;)